# Find "most used items" per "level" in big csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather big csv file and I want to find out which items are used the most at a certain player level.

So one column I'm looking at has all the player levels (from 1 to 30) another column has all the item names (e.g. knife_1, knife_2, etc.) and yet another column lists backpacks (backback_1, backpack_2, etc.).
Now I want to check which is the most used knife and backpack for player level 1, for player level 2, player level 3, etc.

What I've tried was this but when I tried to verify it in Excel (with countifs) the results were different:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
#getting the columns I need:
df = df[["playerLevel", "playerKnife", "playerBackpack"]]

print(df.loc[df["playerLevel"] == 1].mode())
```

In my head, this should locate all the rows with playerLevel 1 and then only print out the most used items for that level. However, I wanted to double-check and used "countifs" in excel which gave me a different result.

Maybe I'm thinking too simple (or complicated) so I hope you can either verify that my code should be correct or point out the error.

I'm also looking for an easy way to then go through all levels automatically and print out the most used items for each level.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Dataframe example. Just imagine there are thousands of players that can range from level 1 to level 30. And especially on higher levels, they have access to a lot of knives and backpacks. So the combinations are limitless.

```
index   playerLevel  playerKnife  playerBackpack
0       1        knife_1      backpack_1
1       2        knife_2      backpack_1
2       3        knife_1      backpack_2
3       1        knife_2      backpack_1
4       2        knife_3      backpack_2
5       1        knife_1      backpack_1
6       15       knife_13     backpack_12
7       13       knife_10     backpack_9
8       1        knife_1      backpack_2
```

Comment: Can you please add a brief, but representative, example dataframe (say, 10 lines at most). Preferably in code form, so that copy-pasting it will automatically create that example dataframe.

Comment: "countifs" don't mean anything to me. So since I don't know what you did in Excel, for all I know, that may be incorrect.

Comment: You could probably also use a group-by for the playerLevel, and then run .mode() on the result to obtain the mode per level. That would be a straightforward Pandas one-liner.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added a demo dataframe.

Could you also please expand on the "group-by" idea?

Comment: I've edited your dataframe, because it wasn't really programmer friendly to parse. Having it as pure code would have been a lot easier, in fact.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to add it as pure code.

Comment: A quick `df.to_records(index=False)` already gets you a long way: might need some formatting, and add the columns, but then it's easy to read with `pd.DataFrame.from_records()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
data = """\
index   playerLevel  playerKnife  playerBackpack
0       1        knife_1      backpack_1
1       2        knife_2      backpack_1
2       3        knife_1      backpack_2
3       1        knife_2      backpack_1
4       2        knife_3      backpack_2
5       1        knife_1      backpack_1
6       15       knife_13     backpack_12
7       13       knife_10     backpack_9
8       1        knife_1      backpack_2
"""

import io
import pandas as pd

stream = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(stream, sep='\s+')
df = df.drop('index', axis='columns')
print(df.groupby('playerLevel').agg(pd.Series.mode))
```

yields

```
                    playerKnife            playerBackpack
playerLevel
1                       knife_1                backpack_1
2            [knife_2, knife_3]  [backpack_1, backpack_2]
3                       knife_1                backpack_2
13                     knife_10                backpack_9
15                     knife_13               backpack_12
```

Note that the result of `df.groupby('playerLevel').agg(pd.Series.mode)` is a DataFrame, so you can assign that result and use it as a normal dataframe.

---

For data plain from a CSV file, simply use

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = df[['playerLevel, 'playerKnife', 'playerBackpack']] # or whichever columns you want
stats = df.groupby('playerLevel').agg(pd.Series.mode))  # stats will be dataframe as well
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My brain is pretty fried at the moment and I haven't used "io" yet.
I'll try to apply what you suggested to my case using my csv file.

However, if that's easy for you, could you maybe write it as if the data would come from a huge csv file with way more columns (as it does in my case)?

Maybe just how I started with reading the csv file, getting the columns I need, and then doing the thing you did?

Either way, I'll try figuring that part out but will need a couple of hours break first.

Thanks again.

Comment: `io` isn't necessary. Just use `pd.read_csv()` or whatever you do to get the dataframe. The `io` part is just a workaround to read the text data into a dataframe.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.
I'll let you know once I applied your suggestion to my case.

Comment: See my addition below the line as well.

Comment: Tried it and it's looking good. I guess I did something wrong in Excel which just confused me even more.
Thanks again!